# how to submit a form and display output without refreshing

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I'm trying to create a simple calculator which gets an input number from the user and shows the calculated output below it. The code works fine but it redirects and reloads the page, obviously. I don't want that I want the output to be displayed as soon as the user fills the form. I have 0 knowledge of js and ajax so I would appreciate you guys helping me with that part. I searched a lot but couldn't understand what to do.
this is my form:

```
<form id="myform" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Enter first number: <input type="text" name="num1"><br><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

and this is the output bellow the form I want:

```
<h1>congrats!</h1>
```

as simple as that. fill the form, submit and display a simple message without refreshing

Comment: ***create a simple calculator*** - if your calculator does not getting any data from your server and if it's simple calculation than you can do this with javascript on client side but if you want to get data from server than you've to use [Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you have zero knowledge and could not produce any code you will most likely face a lot of problem, AJAX vs Django form is another level of complexity and will not implement unless you are 100% sure that will add something to the UX, but in short.

Using Jquery you could built an **Ajax call** to a **Django view** :

**JS Script:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $("form").submit(function (event) {
        var formData = {
          justification: $("#justification").val(),
          

        };
    
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "{% url 'django-view'  %}",
          data: formData,
          dataType: "json",
          encode: true,
        }).done(function (data) {
          
          if (data.success) {
            console.log("error");
    
         
          } else {
           # display your text somewhere in your page
          }
        });
    
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    });
```

**Django View :**

```
@csrf_exempt
def form_post(request):
    # Do something with your data
    text = request.POST.get("num1")
    print(text)
    return JsonResponse({"text": text})
```

As you can see you need a lot more to work with Ajax, you need a good understanding of Django form, a good enough one for Ajax and JS and finally how asynchronous works.